Variational Quantum Linear Solver
I'm studying quantum computing right now and trying to implement variational quantum linear solver to solve a system of linear equations. From what I have understood from the paper written by Carlos Bravo Prieto, I can't find the exact solution vector x but a vector that is proportional to the target answer. From here, I am trying to infer the actual solution by taking a square root of my measurement result and multiplying the normalization factor to my measurement result. However, in this process I lose the signs of the the elements in the solution vector. Is there any way or suggestion on how to determine the signs of the elements in the solution vector?

Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/31472/10454
